# Play audio before finish();

Tags: android

I have method `playAudio();` I want execute this method, after call `finish()` on `Activity`. When I call finish, the audio breaks.

Sample Activity A and B I want this

A (front and call B)
B (front)
B (play sound before! after finish())
A (front...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overrride the `onDestroy` Method. There you can play your sound and then call the super method to finish.
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29